# How to open emacs with a buffer containing the input?

Tags: emacs, buffer

I want to make something like:

```
cat somefile | emacs
```

and this should open emacs with a buffer containing somefile contents.

Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're flexible about the format of the command, some shells have process substitution via temporary files.  For example, [in zsh you could do](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html):

```
emacs =(cat somefile)
```

Any process that generates output can be used in the parentheses. Zsh will save it to a temporary file, then invoke emacs with that filename.

Answer (score 1):

Usually Emacs users prefer to have a long running Emacs instance rather
than opening and closing frequently. Bearing that in mind, you could try
doing the following in an Emacs buffer:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>  <kbd>i</kbd> `file name`

to insert the contents of a file into the current buffer. You could also try using:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd>  `some shell command` <kbd>RET</kbd>

if you want to insert output of any general shell command inserted into
the buffer.